# Change headers default font on Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've just upgraded to Vuetify 2.0 and my fonts are totally broken.
I've managed to change the font on the project by:

```css
.v-application {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif!important;
}
```

But the headings that have applied classes like .display-1, .display-2 are still taking the Vuetify default (Roboto) because it has an !important in the Vuetify default styles.

How could I change the font for the entire project, overriding Vuetify's default?

Comment: See [SASS variables in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables#sass-variables).

Comment: can you share what is inside your `main.js` and `vuetify.js`?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default font for a specific type of typography like `h1` and `h2` and specifically the `font-family` property in the following manner in a global css file for example:

```
$headings: (
    'h1': (
        'font-family': 'Calibri',
        'size': 60px,
        'line-height': 60px,
        'weight': 400
    ),
    'h2': (
        'font': 'Ariel',
        'size': 48px,
        'line-height': 48px,
        'weight': 400
    ),
)
```

And than you can give these utility classes in the Vuetify way like so `class="text-h1"` or `class="text-h2"`

You could do the same in Vuetify to override the following built in(and exposed via API for modifications) utility classes:

- `h3`
- `h4`
- `h5`
- `h6`
- `body-1`
- `body-2`
- `subtitle-1`
- `subtitle-2`
- `button`
- `caption`
- `overline`

If you need any further utility classes, for example that are derived from your internal design system you can add them in that global scss/css file and I recommend doing so while keeping the Vuetify naming convention.

For example if you need a `body-3` or `subtitle-3` you could add them like so

```
.text-body-3 {
    // your custom style
}

.text-subtitle-3 {
    // your custom style
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vuetify 2.x you can customize scss variables in your variables.scss file.  You probably need to set the `$body-font-family` and `$heading-font-family` variables.
There are a lot of variables documented [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/vuetify/#sass-variables) and many changed around Vuetify 2.3.

An example:

```
$font-size-root: 18px;
$body-font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
$heading-font-family: 'Libre Caslon Text', serif;
$btn-text-transform: none;
```

---

Additional information for overriding specific styles:

You can further override individual styles such as `text-h1` by adding a $headings to the same file.

```
$headings: (
      'h1': (
      'size': 4.0rem,
      'weight': 400,
      'line-height': 4.444rem,
      'letter-spacing': 1em,
      'text-transform': false
    )
)
```

The valid values you can customize are listed on the [typography](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#typography) doc.  Those currently include:

- h1
- h2
- h3
- h4
- h5
- h6
- subtitle-1
- subtitle-2
- body-1
- body-2
- button
- caption
- overline

These all generate `text-X` classes. ex: `text-body-2`

Also its important to note that **even if you override these styles it will not change the type settings for elements of the same name** (like h1).  Instead you need to **apply that style with `class="text-h1"`**.  This is easy to miss in the docs.

Right:
`<h1 class="text-h1">my header</h1>`

Wrong:
`<h1>my header</h1>`

*Also if you're not yet on 2.3 the names are different.  If you follow github issues there have been a lot of changes around typography leading to this current system.*